# How to export very high poly mesh?

Tags: export, sculpting, obj

So, basically, I sculpted a 23 million poly mesh inside Blender. Everything went smoothly, but now I need to bake normals and displacement maps. I can't do it inside blender, every time I press Bake, blender just crashes. So I assume blender can't bake things from very high poly objects.

So, I'm trying to export the mesh to bake in other software but the problem is that Blender keeps corrupting the files. I've tried exporting it as an OBJ three times and each time takes about 10 min and gives me a file that other software fails to read.

So, is there a way for me to export this mesh or was using Blender to Sculpt high poly meshes a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Blender should be capable of doing high poly baking, it all depends on the power of your hardware.

A workaround to this should be the **`Decimate`** modifier.

When you add it, lower the **`Ratio`** value on the Decimate modifier if you're using the **`Collapse`** option, or increase the **`Iterations`** if you're using the **`Un-subdivide`** option.

[image]

This will reduce the poly count and help you bake your mesh inside Blender.

23 Million is a little too much even for a high poly model. If you don't want the `Decimate` way, you could use the **`Remesh`** modifier or use the remesh in sculpt mode:

## Remesh

Go into sculpt mode. On the top bar, you will see a dropdown menu called `Remesh`. You can play with the settings (The lower the voxel size the higher polys your mesh will have) and then press the `Remesh` button to get your result.

[image]

Comment: If I decrease the detail, then skin pores, wrinkles will be gone. This is not a solution whatsoever. 23 million is just bare minimum. Most sculpts nowadays are 50-80 million polys but that's using Zbrush. So if I have to ruin all my work in order to bake something, then I'm simply going to continue using Zbrush. Blender seems to not be ready yet for proper high detail sculpting.

Comment: @Filnisius Well... My (expensive and pretty powerful, though I agree not near the best) computer's max is around 15-20 million `faces`. I don't know what else may be the solution until someone else answers, but yes, I guess you have a point in using ZBrush over Blender for sculpting (it's paid software, and why not use it when you have it ;) )